# Why test_normality method and jarque_bera function from statsmodels give different results?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, statsmodels

I encountered an issue while testing a model from statsmodels. It is a time-series model, called SARIMAX. I printed `test_normality` and `jarque_bera` results, and I observed that they are different:

```
best_model_fit.test_normality(method = None)

sm.stats.stattools.jarque_bera(best_model_fit.resid, axis=0)
```

[image]

[image]

I believe the issue is related to the model's **residuals**. I'm uncertain whether the first method uses `best_model_fit.resid` or not. In the initial approach, it's not clear what inputs are included or adjusted. I reviewed the documentation but both methods are Jarque-Bera, and found that there are no specific parameters that could lead to differences in the results.

How can this be explained?

`best_model_fit` is already fitted model.

Comment: What kind of model? statsmodels contains several different `test_normality` methods, depending on the model used. Please edit & update your post to clarify explicitly.

Comment: Generally speaking, what these methods return are different *test statistics*, which do not have any reason to be equal (or even comparable) between them.

Comment: I don’t think so. Actually, both ways using same test, called Jarque-Bera. In the documentation, test_normality has  a parameter called method which we can include only ‘jarquebera’ So if it is the same test, both ways should return the same results. @desertnaut

Comment: But why you don't explicitly ask for `method = 'jarquebera'`, as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResults.test_normality.html), and you insist on `method=None` instead?

Comment: Although it is `None`, It returns still `jarquebera`, when `method = None` included the most appropriate way will be chosen as a method. `jarquebera` is only method there, so it will be chosen. Finally, I found an answer to the question it is related to **residuals** like I thought, I will share it when I am available. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I'm encountering associates to the **residuals** being utilized in the `test_normality` function. Both the methods, `best_model_fit.test_normality()` and `sm.stats.stattools.jarque_bera`, essentially serve the same purpose.

```
def test_normality(self, method):

        if method is None:
            method = 'jarquebera'

        if self.standardized_forecasts_error is None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot compute test statistic when standardized'
                             ' forecast errors have not been computed.')

        if method == 'jarquebera':
            from statsmodels.stats.stattools import jarque_bera
            d = np.maximum(self.loglikelihood_burn, self.nobs_diffuse)
            output = []
            for i in range(self.model.k_endog):
                resid = self.filter_results.standardized_forecasts_error[i, d:]
                mask = ~np.isnan(resid)
                output.append(jarque_bera(resid[mask]))
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError('Invalid normality test method.')

        return np.array(output)
```

The `test_normality` method utilizes the `.filter_results.standardized_forecasts_error[i, d:]` attribute, which is associated with a Kalman Filter instance. This approach is particularly useful when dealing with missing data. The test is conducted on the standardized residuals, excluding those that correspond to missing observations. In my specific case, both `d` and `i` are set to 1, leading to the removal of the residual for the first observation. For a more comprehensive understanding, please refer to the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.html#MLEResults).

By incorporating `best_model_fit.resid[1:]` into `sm.stats.stattools.jarque_bera`, the outcomes of both `best_model_fit.test_normality()` and `best_model_fit.summary()` will converge.